# OpenSL ES Android input microphone scrambled

Tags: android, c++, opensl

I am using the [Superpowered](http://superpowered.com) library on Android, and it is based on OpenSL. I want to retrieve the sound from my phone's microphone or a headset, and I can activate the input recording but the sound is scrambled (I only hear noise).

Do you have any idea what could cause this ? If it can be of any help, I run Android 5.1 on a Nexus 5.

Thank you in advance !

Sample code :

```
    #include "SuperpoweredAndroidAudioIO.h"
    #include android/log.h
    #include SLES/OpenSLES.h
    #include SLES/OpenSLES_Android.h
    #include pthread.h

    typedef struct SuperpoweredAndroidAudioIOInternals {
        pthread_mutex_t mutex;
        void *clientdata;
        audioProcessingCallback callback;
        SLObjectItf openSLEngine, outputMix, outputBufferQueue, inputBufferQueue;
        SLAndroidSimpleBufferQueueItf outputBufferQueueInterface, inputBufferQueueInterface;
        short int *fifobuffer, *silence;
        int samplerate, buffersize, fifoCapacity, fifoFirstSample, fifoLastSample, latencySamples;
        bool hasOutput, hasInput;
        SuperpoweredResampler *resampler;
    } SuperpoweredAndroidAudioIOInternals;

    static inline void checkRoom(SuperpoweredAndroidAudioIOInternals *internals) {
        if (internals->fifoLastSample + internals->buffersize >= internals->fifoCapacity) { // If there is no room at the fifo buffer's end, move everything to the beginning.
            int samplesInFifo = internals->fifoLastSample - internals->fifoFirstSample;
            if (samplesInFifo > 0) memmove(internals->fifobuffer, internals->fifobuffer + internals->fifoFirstSample * 2, samplesInFifo * 8);
            internals->fifoFirstSample = 0;
            internals->fifoLastSample = samplesInFifo;
        };
    }

    static void SuperpoweredAndroidAudioIO_InputCallback(SLAndroidSimpleBufferQueueItf caller, void *pContext) { // Audio input comes here.
        SuperpoweredAndroidAudioIOInternals *internals = (SuperpoweredAndroidAudioIOInternals *)pContext;
        pthread_mutex_lock(&internals->mutex);
        checkRoom(internals);

        short int *input = internals->fifobuffer + internals->fifoLastSample * 2;
        internals->fifoLastSample += internals->buffersize;

        if (internals->hasOutput) {
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&internals->mutex);
            (*caller)->Enqueue(caller, input, internals->buffersize * 4);
        } else {
            short int *process = internals->fifobuffer + internals->fifoFirstSample * 2;
            internals->fifoFirstSample += internals->buffersize;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&internals->mutex);

            (*caller)->Enqueue(caller, input, internals->buffersize * 4);
            internals->callback(internals->clientdata, process, internals->buffersize, internals->samplerate);
        };
    }

    static void SuperpoweredAndroidAudioIO_OutputCallback(SLAndroidSimpleBufferQueueItf caller, void *pContext) {
        SuperpoweredAndroidAudioIOInternals *internals = (SuperpoweredAndroidAudioIOInternals *)pContext;
        pthread_mutex_lock(&internals->mutex);

        if (!internals->hasInput) {
            checkRoom(internals);
            short int *process = internals->fifobuffer + internals->fifoLastSample * 2;
            internals->fifoLastSample += internals->buffersize;
            short int *output = internals->fifobuffer + internals->fifoFirstSample * 2;
            internals->fifoFirstSample += internals->buffersize;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&internals->mutex);

            if (!internals->callback(internals->clientdata, process, internals->buffersize, internals->samplerate)) memset(process, 0, internals->buffersize * 4);
            (*caller)->Enqueue(caller, output, internals->buffersize * 4);
        } else {
            if (internals->fifoLastSample - internals->fifoFirstSample >= internals->latencySamples) {
                short int *output = internals->fifobuffer + internals->fifoFirstSample * 2;
                internals->fifoFirstSample += internals->buffersize;
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&internals->mutex);

                if (!internals->callback(internals->clientdata, output, internals->buffersize, internals->samplerate)) memset(output, 0, internals->buffersize * 4);
                (*caller)->Enqueue(caller, output, internals->buffersize * 4);
            } else {
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&internals->mutex);
                (*caller)->Enqueue(caller, internals->silence, internals->buffersize * 4); // dropout, not enough audio input
            };
        };
    }

    SuperpoweredAndroidAudioIO::SuperpoweredAndroidAudioIO(int samplerate, int buffersize, bool enableInput, bool enableOutput, audioProcessingCallback callback, void *clientdata, int latencySamples) {
        static const SLboolean requireds[2] = { SL_BOOLEAN_TRUE, SL_BOOLEAN_TRUE };

        internals = new SuperpoweredAndroidAudioIOInternals;
        memset(internals, 0, sizeof(SuperpoweredAndroidAudioIOInternals));
        pthread_mutex_init(&internals->mutex, NULL);
        internals->samplerate = samplerate;
        internals->buffersize = buffersize;
        internals->clientdata = clientdata;
        internals->callback = callback;
        internals->hasInput = enableInput;
        internals->hasOutput = enableOutput;
        internals->silence = (short int *)malloc(buffersize * 4);
        internals->latencySamples = latencySamples resampler = new SuperpoweredResampler();

        memset(internals->silence, 0, buffersize * 4);

        internals->fifoCapacity = buffersize * 100;
        int fifoBufferSizeBytes = internals->fifoCapacity * 4 + buffersize * 4;
        internals->fifobuffer = (short int *)malloc(fifoBufferSizeBytes);
        memset(internals->fifobuffer, 0, fifoBufferSizeBytes);

        // Create the OpenSL ES engine.
        slCreateEngine(&internals->openSLEngine, 0, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
        (*internals->openSLEngine)->Realize(internals->openSLEngine, SL_BOOLEAN_FALSE);
        SLEngineItf openSLEngineInterface = NULL;
        (*internals->openSLEngine)->GetInterface(internals->openSLEngine, SL_IID_ENGINE, &openSLEngineInterface);
        // Create the output mix.
        (*openSLEngineInterface)->CreateOutputMix(openSLEngineInterface, &internals->outputMix, 0, NULL, NULL);
        (*internals->outputMix)->Realize(internals->outputMix, SL_BOOLEAN_FALSE);
        SLDataLocator_OutputMix outputMixLocator = { SL_DATALOCATOR_OUTPUTMIX, internals->outputMix };

        if (enableInput) { // Create the input buffer queue.
            SLDataLocator_IODevice deviceInputLocator = { SL_DATALOCATOR_IODEVICE, SL_IODEVICE_AUDIOINPUT, SL_DEFAULTDEVICEID_AUDIOINPUT, NULL };
            SLDataSource inputSource = { &deviceInputLocator, NULL };
            SLDataLocator_AndroidSimpleBufferQueue inputLocator = { SL_DATALOCATOR_ANDROIDSIMPLEBUFFERQUEUE, 1 };
            SLDataFormat_PCM inputFormat = { SL_DATAFORMAT_PCM, 2, samplerate * 1000, SL_PCMSAMPLEFORMAT_FIXED_16, SL_PCMSAMPLEFORMAT_FIXED_16, SL_SPEAKER_FRONT_LEFT | SL_SPEAKER_FRONT_RIGHT, SL_BYTEORDER_LITTLEENDIAN };
            SLDataSink inputSink = { &inputLocator, &inputFormat };
            const SLInterfaceID inputInterfaces[1] = { SL_IID_ANDROIDSIMPLEBUFFERQUEUE };
            (*openSLEngineInterface)->CreateAudioRecorder(openSLEngineInterface, &internals->inputBufferQueue, &inputSource, &inputSink, 1, inputInterfaces, requireds);
            (*internals->inputBufferQueue)->Realize(internals->inputBufferQueue, SL_BOOLEAN_FALSE);
        };

        if (enableOutput) { // Create the output buffer queue.
            SLDataLocator_AndroidSimpleBufferQueue outputLocator = { SL_DATALOCATOR_ANDROIDSIMPLEBUFFERQUEUE, 1 };
            SLDataFormat_PCM outputFormat = { SL_DATAFORMAT_PCM, 2, samplerate * 1000, SL_PCMSAMPLEFORMAT_FIXED_16, SL_PCMSAMPLEFORMAT_FIXED_16, SL_SPEAKER_FRONT_LEFT | SL_SPEAKER_FRONT_RIGHT, SL_BYTEORDER_LITTLEENDIAN };
            SLDataSource outputSource = { &outputLocator, &outputFormat };
            const SLInterfaceID outputInterfaces[1] = { SL_IID_BUFFERQUEUE };
            SLDataSink outputSink = { &outputMixLocator, NULL };
            (*openSLEngineInterface)->CreateAudioPlayer(openSLEngineInterface, &internals->outputBufferQueue, &outputSource, &outputSink, 1, outputInterfaces, requireds);
            (*internals->outputBufferQueue)->Realize(internals->outputBufferQueue, SL_BOOLEAN_FALSE);
        };

        if (enableInput) { // Initialize and start the input buffer queue.
            (*internals->inputBufferQueue)->GetInterface(internals->inputBufferQueue, SL_IID_ANDROIDSIMPLEBUFFERQUEUE, &internals->inputBufferQueueInterface);
            (*internals->inputBufferQueueInterface)->RegisterCallback(internals->inputBufferQueueInterface, SuperpoweredAndroidAudioIO_InputCallback, internals);
            SLRecordItf recordInterface;
            (*internals->inputBufferQueue)->GetInterface(internals->inputBufferQueue, SL_IID_RECORD, &recordInterface);
            (*internals->inputBufferQueueInterface)->Enqueue(internals->inputBufferQueueInterface, internals->fifobuffer, buffersize * 4);
            (*recordInterface)->SetRecordState(recordInterface, SL_RECORDSTATE_RECORDING);
        };

        if (enableOutput) { // Initialize and start the output buffer queue.
            (*internals->outputBufferQueue)->GetInterface(internals->outputBufferQueue, SL_IID_BUFFERQUEUE, &internals->outputBufferQueueInterface);
            (*internals->outputBufferQueueInterface)->RegisterCallback(internals->outputBufferQueueInterface, SuperpoweredAndroidAudioIO_OutputCallback, internals);
            (*internals->outputBufferQueueInterface)->Enqueue(internals->outputBufferQueueInterface, internals->fifobuffer, buffersize * 4);
            SLPlayItf outputPlayInterface;
            (*internals->outputBufferQueue)->GetInterface(internals->outputBufferQueue, SL_IID_PLAY, &outputPlayInterface);
            (*outputPlayInterface)->SetPlayState(outputPlayInterface, SL_PLAYSTATE_PLAYING);
        };
    }

    SuperpoweredAndroidAudioIO::~SuperpoweredAndroidAudioIO() {
        free(internals->fifobuffer);
        free(internals->silence);
        pthread_mutex_destroy(&internals->mutex);
        delete internals;
    }
```

Comment: Can you please show your code utilising this class? This code seems like 100% equal to the class shipped with Superpowered, which sets up audio system input/output.